printf in assembly NASM x86 print only once of the array in the loop
Calling printf function inside my x86 code, outputs only the first number in the array and stops working even if I remove the call exit. It prints out the first element in the array infinity
extern printf
extern exit
section .data
    array db 1,2,3,4
    fmt  db "%d" , 0xa, 0
section .text
global main

main:
    mov     esi, 0
    jmp     loopfun

loopfun:
    mov     ecx, 0
    mov     cl, [array + esi]
    push    ecx
    push    fmt
    call    printf
    pop     ecx
    push    1
    call    exit
    inc     esi
    cmp     esi, 4
    jne     loopfun

    mov     eax, 1
    mov     ebx, 0
    int     0x80  


Works here. Note that you unbalance the stack because you push 2 things but only remove 1. Does not causes a problem in this case though.

Commenting out the push 1 and call exit, yeah it works for me, too, printing 1 through 4 on separate lines. (Unless I redirect to a file, since then stdout is full-buffered and doesn't get flushed by a raw int 0x80 exit system call).  The source you posted only prints the first element because it calls exit inside the loop.  Post a [mcve] of the source that actually has one of the bugs you describe.

@PeterCordes yep thank you I didn't focus with this but I thought exit do action for only the printf calling line not for the whole program did you mean it's the same as int 0x80

int 0x80 by itself is just the system call interface, what it does depends on the code in eax. But yes, exit terminates your program. See man exit

call exit is not exactly the same as call _exit or eax=1 / int 0x80, although similar.  Syscall implementation of exit() / How come _exit(0) (exiting by syscall) prevents me from receiving any stdout content?.  If you just want to complete printf without exiting, you could push 0 / call fflush (in C, fflush(NULL);), to make sure the stdout buffer is flushed.  Other than that, printf is already done when it returns.
